# alignment of page number to top right in overleaf

Tags: latex

How do I align my page number to top right corner in overleaf?
I tried

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{phdthesis}{%
\fancyhf 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\fancyhf` is missing its mandatory argument. It works if you use `\fancyhf{}` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{phdthesis}{%
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{phdthesis}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```